# 複数のアプリで、共通のポイントを使用することはできるでしょうか？

Tags: ios, android, アプリ内課金

IOSとAndroidのアプリを２つ作ろうと考えています。

アプリAとアプリBは、兄弟アプリのような関係にあり、
機能とジャンルが似ています。

両方とも、アプリ内ポイントを購入するタイプの課金がある、
インストール無料で、有料ポイントもあるアプリです。

そこで、アプリAとアプリBで、共通のポイントを用意しようと思っております。
例えば、アプリAで買ったポイントが、アプリBでも利用できるようなイメージです。

そのような課金、ポイント消費方法は、
Google・Appleの規約（レギュレーション）的に、問題のないものなのでしょうか？

ご存知のかた、お教えいただけますと幸いです。
参考になるURLをお教えおいただくだけでも構いません。

何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10198175730

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/154524

Answer (score 1):

App Store Reviewガイドラインに
https://developer.apple.com/jp/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase

> App内課金で手に入れたコンテンツ、機能、消耗アイテムを直接的または間接的に他のユーザーに譲渡できるようにすることはできません

とあるので、今回のケースも難しいと思われます。

> アプリAで買ったポイントが、アプリBでも利用できるようなイメージ

これが「他のユーザー」として扱われるかどうかがポイントですね。

Answer (score 0):

アプリの範囲を超えたサービスの場合はアプリ外決済にするのが一般的です
アプリ内決済でも通ると思いますが（例：アプリゲーム内ポイント）

Answer (score 0):

Appleについてのみですが、下記の条件の場合は可能かと思われます。

・同一開発アカウントが出しているアプリであること
・複数AppleIDを跨いで使用できないこと
・Androidなど他プラットフォームアプリと共有できないこと

それ以外は既に出ているAppleガイドラインを一読して見ることをオススメします。